# Run postgresql initdb script during build in Yocto

Tags: postgresql, embedded-linux, yocto

I am building image in Yocto with PostgreSQL. I have my system as read only with one partition as read/write.

Is there any way to run PostgreSQL initdb directly in Yocto during build so I don't have to run it after first boot? I need it because I am using RAUC as an update system and want to generate image from Yocto which is completely ready and does not make any changes to system after boot like running initdb script.

I couldn't find any recipe which does this so I am not sure if its even possible. I am kinda new to PostgreSQL and I know that the initdb script generates some config files but not sure what other stuff its happening during its run.

Comment: The initdb script expects the target's rootfs, but Yocto is running with the host's filesystem. How do you expect to reconcile that difference? You are essentially asking an XY question.